# Having trouble building a simple if/else if/else functionality with ANTLR/LLVM/C++

Tags: c++, llvm, antlr4, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I've got a barely functional compiled language working with ANTLR4, LLVM and the C++ LLVM API. I was able to get a simple `if` statement to work properly, but I'm struggling to add the `else if` and `else` components. For what it's worth, I've tried a hundred different google searches but haven't found anything that has worked for me yet.

Here's the relevant excerpts from my `Lexer.g4` and `Parser.g4`:

```
// Lexer.g4

If: 'if';
Else: 'else';

// Parser.g4

condition:
    OpeningParen expression ClosingParen body
    ;

ifStatement:
    If condition (Else If condition)* (Else body)?
    ;
```

and here's the pertinent code in my `Visitor.cpp` file:

```cpp
void Visitor::visitIfStatement(FooParser::IfStatementContext *context)
{
    bool evaluatedBlock = false;
    auto afterBlock = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(builder.getContext());

    for (auto &conditionContext : context->condition()) {
        auto expression = this->visitExpression(conditionContext->expression());
        auto type = expression->getType();
        auto body = this->visitBody(conditionContext->body());

        if (type->isIntegerTy()) {
            auto zero = llvm::ConstantInt::get(type, 0);
            auto condition = builder.CreateICmpNE(expression, zero);

            if ((bool) condition == 1) {
                builder.CreateBr(body.mainBlock);
                builder.SetInsertPoint(body.afterBlock);
                evaluatedBlock = true;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            // throw an exception here.
        }
    }

    // If we make it to ELSE and an else block actually exists...
    if (!evaluatedBlock && context->body) {
        auto body = this->visitBody(context->body());
        builder.CreateBr(body.mainBlock);
    }

    builder.SetInsertPoint(afterBlock);
}
```

I believe my issues are:

1. `if ((bool) condition == 1) {` -- I'm almost certain this is patently wrong
2. `if (!evaluatedBlock && context->body) {` -- here, the intent of `context->body` is to make sure the else statement actually has a body (i.e. else { ... } exists) but I'm definitely not getting this right.

Apologies in advance for the very basic questions. I learn best by getting my hands dirty and breaking things until I finally figure out the concept, but I'm stuck on this one...

Comment: You don't need the cast nor the comparison.  Just say `if( condition )`.  Exploit the "truthiness" attributes of the standard types.

Comment: You need the `if (condition)` to occur at runtime, not compile-time. Use `builder.CreateCondBr(Cond, TrueBlock, FalseBlock);`.

Comment: The way you write this is like some well-regarded compilers, but a lot of people make lifer simpler for themselves by generating an AST in parsing, then generating IR from the AST. The AST will be a tree that you define for your language, and you write three functions for it: The parser, the generator and the debug dumper that helps you find out whether each bug is in the parsing code or IR generation code. (The people who don't need that dumper are smarter than I am. Their compilers are well-regarded and they are very smart.)